# jquery dialog with issue after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

---

I have a page that call from *ajax* a form with a specific target. this form has a delete entry and for that a warning with a *jQuery dialog* is used. everything works great. 
BUT : 
After doing the change or even not doing it, when I open another form (different form by ajax call) and I call the same code below described. When It is submit the dialog the #var_blabla as a value of 1 (the value of the first *dialog* opened/loaded) and for that moment should be '2'.

I try to figure it out.. So my problem I guess is not for the *dialog* it self, since I try to load a second page without the constructor and the *dialog* didn't open (what should be expected). 
The problem is on the button 'Submit Delete' that has an event function and it stays active over another that is created.

The site have a lot of forms and many dialogs for each form, is there a wait to unbind, or destroy completely the dialog and the buttons? Ideas please?

Thanks

---

simplified 1st dialog call code:

```
$("#dialog-confirm-elimina").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height:220,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Submit Delete': function() { $('#var_blabla').val('1');
                       $('#form_submit').submit();
                       $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
                       $(this).dialog('close');
        }
}
```

simplified 2nd dialog call code:

```
  $("#dialog-confirm-elimina").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:220,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Submit Delete': function() { $('#var_blabla').val('2');
                           $('#form_submit').submit();
                           $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                           $(this).dialog('close');
            }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
submited=false;
var toggleOpened = true;
$("#admin_retractil_1").click(function () {

    if(!toggleOpened){
        $('#admin_retractil_1').toggleClass('toggleGESBHeadown');
        toggleOpened=true;
        }
    else{
        $('#admin_retractil_1').toggleClass('toggleGESBHeadown');
        toggleOpened=false;
        }
            var objecto = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#' + objecto+"_div").slideToggle("slow");
        });

var toggleOpened2 = false;
$("#admin_retractil_2").click(function () {

    if(!toggleOpened2){
        $('#admin_retractil_2').toggleClass('toggleGESAHeadown');
        toggleOpened2=true;
        }
    else{
        $('#admin_retractil_2').toggleClass('toggleGESAHeadown');
        toggleOpened2=false;
        }
            var objecto = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#' + objecto+"_div").slideToggle("slow");
        });

$(document).ready(function() {
                //$( "button").button();
        var locked = true;
        $( "#EditDataForm").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-locked" }});
        $( "#EditDataForm" ).click(function() {
                    if(locked){
                        locked = false;
                        $( "#EditDataForm").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-unlocked" }});
                        $('#edit_data_admin').slideToggle("slow");
                        $('#view_data_admin').slideToggle("slow");

                   }else{
                        locked = true;
                        $( "#EditDataForm").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-locked" }});
                        $('#edit_data_admin').slideToggle("slow");
                        $('#view_data_admin').slideToggle("slow");
                    }

                    return false; });


        $( "#DelDataForm").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-scissors" }});
                $( "#DelDataForm" ).click(function() {
                    $('#dialog-confirm-del').dialog('open');
                    return false; });

                /*abre popup de alerta de eliminar */
                arrayRemove.push("dialog-confirm-del");   
                $("#dialog-confirm-del").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height:220,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Remove Stuff': function() {
                                        $('#sel_action_form').val('TypoDesClients_DelDef');
                                        $('#name').val('_____');
                                        $('#form_submit').submit();
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancelar: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');

                }
            }
        });

                $( "#AcceptChanges").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check" }});
                $("#form_submeter").validator({ 
                    position: 'center right',
                    offset: [0, 0],
                    message: '<div><em /></div>'
                }).bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
                    var numSucceeded = els.length,
                        numExpected = $(this).data('validator').getInputs().length;

                    if (numSucceeded === numExpected) { 
                        if(!submited){submited=true;
                                    SubmitFormSV('form_submit', 'action/action_a.php');
                                    return false;
                                    }else return false;
                    }
                });

$( "#radio" ).buttonset();
$("#1_radio").click(function () { 
    $("#tr_1").show();
});
$("#2_radio").click(function () { 
    $("#tr_1").hide();
    });

});
```

local lib:

```
     function SubmitFormSV(formul, address)
     {       
             DoChecks();
        $("#loading").show("slow");
        $.post(baseURL + address, $('#' + formul).serialize(), function(html){
            $('#content').slideUp("slow", function () {
                AjaxChargePage(html, true);
            });
        });
        $("#loading").hide("slow");
        return false;
     }
```

next the next chuck of javascript is similar to this one.

and with this work because destroy didn't: 
DoChecks() As:

```
$.each(arrayRemove, function() {
    var element = arrayRemove.pop();
    $('#'+element).remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 for updating with your results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're done with dialog 1 try...

```
$("#dialog-confirm-elimina").dialog("destroy");
```

or in your Cancel function...

```
$(this).dialog("destroy");
```

The `.dialog` command creates a new dialog on the element selected. You're doing this twice, and thus having problems. Once the dialog is created it can be reused using open and close methods or destroyed as I've shown above and then recreated.

Comment: BZinK thank you for your answer for starter.

I've tried that before indeed. unfortunately for some reason, that I don't understand, the destroy make his job and after that when I call the other page(by ajax) the dialog of that page doesn't open. And if I go separately to each page while refreshing the entire page it work. I'm working on in trying to find the missing clue.

Comment: Where are you calling "open" for the dialog? You should post more of your code so people can help you.

Comment: well, that's way I ask for help.. when I do the `dialog("destroy")` of the first `.dialog`... the second don't initiate for some reason.

Comment: with the ajax call, the html of the main-content is inserted and with it the javascript call is made with `$(document).ready(function() {....});`

Comment: Update your question with more code. You haven't given us enough to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then finally I got a solution that make everything works. Instead of using the

```
$("#dialog-confirm-elimina").dialog("destroy");
```

I use:

```
$("#dialog-confirm-elimina").remove();
```

I still don't know the reason but clearly don't have the problem anymore.

Thanks for the answer though.

PS: If anyone know how could this append I appreciate to illuminate me about it.Thanks